# How do I make the auto-generated parser class implement an interface in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I am using ANTLR 4 to create a parser, and I have completed my grammar.  I need to inject some Java code into the resulting parser file that ANTLR auto-generates for me.

If I want to include a method in the resulting parser, I can add this to the ANTLR grammar:

```
@parser::members
{
  @Override
  public CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext call()
  {
    return cSnippet();
  }
}
```

If I want to include some import statements, I can add this to the grammar:

```
@header
{
  import java.lang.Thread;
  import java.lang.InterruptedException;
  import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
}
```

If I want to modify the class declaration so that it **implements an interface**, how do I do that?  In other words, this is what ANTLR auto-generates:

```
public class CGrammarParser extends Parser 
{
  ...
}
```

But this is what I want it to generate:

```
public class CGrammarParser extends Parser implements Callable<CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext> 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to **Lucas Trzesniewski**.

To have your ANTLR parser implement an interface, no Java is required in the grammar file (.g4) itself.  Simply do the following:

1) Create an callable parser class that extends the ANTLR parser and implements the interface in question, something like:

```
public class CallableParser extends CGrammarParser implements Callable<CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext>
{
    public CallableParser(TokenStream input)
    {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext call()
    {
        return cSnippet();
    }
}
```

2) Instead of calling your ANTLR parser, call the `CallableParser` instead, like this:

```
CharStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(input);
CGrammarLexer lexer = new CGrammarLexer(in);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
// Instead of doing this...
// CGrammarParser parser = new CGrammarParser(tokens);
// Do this...
CallableParser parser = new CallableParser(tokens);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, not like you describe (via interface(s)). However, you can define a super class your parser should extend from. This super class should, of course, extend ANTLR's `Parser` class. In your own (abstract) parser class, you then define the interfaces you want to implement.

Here's how that could work:

### CallableParser

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;

public abstract class CallableParser extends Parser implements Callable<CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext>
{
    public CallableParser(TokenStream input)
    {
        super(input);
    }
}
```

### CGrammar.g4

```
grammar CGrammar;

options
{
  superClass = CallableParser;
}

@header
{
  import java.lang.Thread;
  import java.lang.InterruptedException;
  import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
}

@parser::members
{
  @Override
  public CGrammarParser.CSnippetContext call()
  {
    return cSnippet();
  }
}

cSnippet
 : ANY*? EOF
 ;

ANY
 : .
 ;
```

Comment: You can also do this the other way around: you can inherit from the generated parser and implement what you need in the derived class (and that's cleaner than using the `@parser::members` construct IMO, since there's more separation between grammar and logic). And just for the record, the answer to this question is even simpler for C# parsers: these are `partial` classes.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this, but it doesn't work.  It throws an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.  If I manually add in the extends and implements that I want (see my question), it works fine.  I feel like this answer is very close, but ANTLR's not happy about it.

Comment: I tried your answer, @LucasTrzesniewski, and it works!  If you want to add an answer to the question, I will accept it as the correct answer.  Thank you.